# Eliminar la propiedad de un objeto cuyo valor es el texto mas largo

Tags: javascript

Escribir una funcion remove , eliminar cualquier propiedad cuyo valor es el texto mas largo.

Este es mi avance...

```js
function remove (num , obj){
  
  let myObject = {
   name:"Rodolfo",
   edad : 23,
   hobby:"ir al cine"
  }
  if(Object.values(myObject)> num){
     
      delete Object.key(myObject);
   }
    return myObject;
}

remove (8,myObject)
```

Porque cuando se ejecuta el codigo , ¿menciona que myObject no esta definido?

Comment: en este caso, myObject es una variable de entorno LOCAL, osea, solo existe dentro de tu función "remove", al intentar usarla fuera de ese entorno local te va a decir que no existe, ya que no la reconoce. Lo que podés hacer es declarar la variable fuera del entorno de tu función, para que te la reconozca en todas partes y no solo dentro de la función

Comment: en efecto como te dice @NachoZveDeLaTorre estas enviando un objeto que no existe x lo cual debes declararlo o definirlo afuera de la funcion que estas llamando(remove)

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una posible solución a su problema:

```js
function removeAtributoConElTextoMasLargo(objeto){
   if(Object.keys(objeto)[0]){
      let masExtenso=Object.keys(objeto)[0];
      for(attr in objeto){
        if( typeof objeto[attr] ==='string'){
          if(objeto[masExtenso].length < objeto[attr].length){
            masExtenso=attr;
          }
        }
      }
      delete objeto[masExtenso];
    }
    return objeto;
}


function remover(valor){
  let myObject = {
     name:"Rodolfo",
     edad : 23,
     hobby:"ir al cine"
  };
  if(valor){
    myObject.name=valor;
  }
  console.log(myObject);
console.log(removeAtributoConElTextoMasLargo(myObject));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" value="el nombre"/>
 <button onclick="remover(document.getElementById('texto').value)">Remover</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código te debería quedar así:

```
let myObject = {};

function remove (num , obj){

myObject = {
name:"Rodolfo",
edad : 23,
hobby:"ir al cine"
}
if(Object.values(myObject)> num){

   delete Object.key(myObject);
}
return myObject;
}

remove (8,myObject)
```